# Django stores uploaded file outside project directory

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2`

I have a model `Course` to create a course and upload banner image as `ImageField()`

```
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='course/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

In my `settings` files located at `app/settings/local.py`

```
# at top of settings file, defined BASE_DIR
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dir')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'static_root')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

The image is uploading perfectly but it's uploaded location is outside of project directory. Say if my project resides in `my_project` directory which contains `app` module and other modules along with `static_dir` to store static files.
But the `static_cdn` directory is created outside `my_project` directory.

I want it to be inside `my_project` directory.

**What is wrong there?**

> Edit 2

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dir')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root')
```

Comment: change `upload_to` parameter to `media/` for just brute forcing

Comment: still main path is same. It creates a directory `static_cdn` outside of project directory and inside id `media` directory

Comment: how about setting , `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR))` ?

Comment: this time it has created `media` directory but still outside of project directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove one os.path.dirname() call , should work fine

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Or you can keep BASE_DIR as it is and change MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC _ROOT

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root') 

 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

I think second option will be best

Comment: I think there is only one `os.path.dirname` call, first one is `join`. And same path is defined for `static_dir`. `static_dir` is inside the application directory and that is working

Comment: I was talking about BASE_DIR setting, by the way I have update my answer second option should work

Comment: removed `os.path.direname` from `MEDIA_ROOT` and it's working

Comment: Great, according to your current settings even your static files will be dumped (collected) outside of your project root dir after running collectstatic command

Comment: I understand, but I have `static_dir` inside project directory and everything is working for static files placed in `static_dir`. I can't see any `static_dir` directory outside of project directory. It could be because of `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dir')
]`?

Comment: set DEBUG = False in you setting, should not work if there is no static_dir directory outside of your project root.
After running
 python manage.py collectstatic
It will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167052/discussion-between-anuj-tbe-and-nagesh-dhope).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to EDIT 2

As you have DEBUG = False your are running in production mode

Please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/

Also you can use http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Also if you set DEBUG = True it should work fine

Recommend: Do not set DEBUG = True in production